# Uniform distribution in statistics

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, data-analysis

I have got data from a sample that is thought to be uniformly distributed. The data is shown below:

[image]

My question is for what range of values for y, is the data not consistent with the distribution at the 5% significant level.

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

Then I did:

$$
\chi^2 = \frac{(y-6)^2}{6} + \frac{(16-y)^2}{12} = \frac{3y^2-56y+328}{12}
$$

$$
v=20
$$

critical value from data table = 10.85

therefore

$$
\chi^2 \leq 10.85
$$

Thus

$$
 \frac{3y^2-56y+328}{12} = 10.85
$$
$$
4.73 \leq y \leq 13.93
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm assuming you intend on using a $\chi^2$ test. How would you set it up?

Comment: I have just update the question with my workings. Could you see if I have done them correctly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a discrete uniform (implied by the ranges in the bins), we see that under the null hypothesis that $X \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1, 20)$, the expected number of observations in the range $\{1, \ldots, 8\}$ in a sample size of $n = 40$ should be $$\frac{8}{20} \cdot 40 = 16,$$ not $12$ as you have in your table.  Similarly, the expected number of observations in $\{9, \ldots, 12\}$ is $8$, and the expected number of observations in $\{13, \ldots, 20\}$ is $16$.  Indeed, the sum of your observed frequencies is $$12 + y + (28-y) = 40,$$ yet your expected frequencies sum only to $12 + 6 + 12 = 30$.

The result of such a test would give an approximate $p$-value.  You could alternatively construct a test based on a likelihood ratio.